# How to read XML namespaces attribute in RDF xml file using go

Tags: xml, go, rdf

I'm tring to parse following XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:eu="http://iec.ch/TC57/CIM100-European#"
    xmlns:md="http://iec.ch/TC57/61970-552/ModelDescription/1#"
    xmlns:cim="http://iec.ch/TC57/CIM100#" > 
  <md:FullModel rdf:about="urn:uuid:52a409c9-72d8-4b5f-bf72-9a22ec9353f7">
   ......
```

by using go `xml.NewDecoder(file).Decode(&model)` method. I'm able to get all 'FullModel' and all following items, however I cannot figure out how to get those namespaces strings values: xmlns:rdf,  xmlns:eu ...

My code: https://go.dev/play/p/qF_2er47_3R

What wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate Go structs from XML you can use generators, for example [miku/zek](https://github.com/miku/zek/). There are also [online version](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/tools/xmltogo/).
This code should work as expected: https://go.dev/play/p/xUShK1Wpk8g

Your root node is `RDF` and `FullModel` its child node, but your described
`FullModel` on the same level as `RDF` in your structs.

If you need to set a name for root node you can use `xml.Name` struct field type. According to the documentation for [encoding/xml](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Marshal):

> The name for the XML elements is taken from, in order of preference:
>
> the tag on the XMLName field, if the data is a struct the value of the
> XMLName field of type Name the tag of the struct field used to obtain
> the data the name of the struct field used to obtain the data the name
> of the marshaled type

Your code:

```
type RDF struct {
    Rdf string `xml:"rdf,attr"`
    Eu  string `xml:"eu,attr"`
    Md  string `xml:"md,attr"`
    Cim string `xml:"cim,attr"`
}

type File_model struct {
    RDF   RDF       `xml:"RDF"`
    Model FullModel `xml:"FullModel"`
}
```

Generated struct:

```
type RDF struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"RDF"`
    Text      string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Rdf       string   `xml:"rdf,attr"`
    Eu        string   `xml:"eu,attr"`
    Md        string   `xml:"md,attr"`
    Cim       string   `xml:"cim,attr"`
    FullModel struct {
        Text                      string `xml:",chardata"`
        About                     string `xml:"about,attr"`
        ...
    } `xml:"FullModel"`
    AccumulatorLimit struct {
        Text                        string `xml:",chardata"`
        ID                          string `xml:"ID,attr"`
        ...
}
```